# WebSharper ui.next site working locally but not in docker

Tags: mono, docker, owin, websharper

I have a site that's build using mono and WebSharper.UI.Next. It's selfhosted (Owin) and works flawlessly on my machine directly. However when I try executing it from within a docker container (FROM mono:3.10-onbuild) requesting one of the WebSHarper script files "dissappear" E.g. WebSharper.Collections.min.js returns a 404.

This behaviour can be reproduced with the project created by WebSHarpers client-server selfhosted Owin project template and the below dockerfile

```
FROM mono:3.10-onbuild
RUN ln -s /usr/src/app/build /usr/src/app/bin
CMD mono ./Site.exe http://*:9000
EXPOSE 9000
```

(`Site` should obviously match the name of the site being used)

Comment: Can you show a reproducer?

Comment: @user2915097 So far any site I've deployed to docker have this behaviour. It can be reproduced with the boiler plate site that's created if you pick the client server owin project template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the trick is to override the default root directory when running in the docker container. changing the CMD from OP to

```
CMD mono ./Site.exe _PublishedWebsites/Site/  http://*:9000
```

Will override the default home dir then I get all the scripts alright.